# Disposing all sql connections

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-pooling, sqlconnection

We are working on a big project which is developed Asp.Net web forms (it added in solution as website, not project).
It has over a hundred thousand lines legacy codes. It requested by approx. 500 concurrent user and now we have connection pool problem that happens usually.

But the real problem is solving this problem is not easy, because there is a hundred thousand instance creating lines of sql connection which is not disposed as well.

Refactoring of all codes could be take a lot of months maybe half of a year. We must find a quick solution for that.

But the good thing is all of that creating sql connection instances managed from one class.

We got an idea. Maybe we can, create a concurrent bag of SqlConnection, then add all created instances in this bag and when current http request is finishing and arriving from asp.net pipeline, dispose all SqlConnection instances.

What is your suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the Connection class you are using. To that subclass add logic to add each newly created connection to your 'bag.' Then use the bag to close all the connections when necessary.

The only refactoring this requires is a global search and replace on the Connection object declaration to use your new class.

The bag would be a static class-level object that is common to all instances of the subclassed connection object.